# xh264 streaming to website using Gstreamer-1.0

Tags: gstreamer

I am very much new to the whole GStreamer-thing, therefore I would be happy if you could help me.

I need to stream a near-zero-latency videosignal from a webcam to a server and them be able to view the stream on a website.
The webcam is linked to a Raspberry Pi 3, because there are space-constraints on the mounting plattform. As a result of using the Pi I really can't transcode the video on the Pi itself. Therefore I bought a Logitech C920 Webcam, which is able to output a raw h264-stream.

By now I managed to view the stream on my windows-machine, but didn't manage to get the whole website-thing working.
My "achivements":

- Sender:

  ```
  gst-launch-1.0 -e -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=5 mtu=60000 ! udpsink host=192.168.0.132 port=5000
  ```

My understanding of this command is: Get the signal of video-device0, which is a h264-stream with a certain width, height and framerate. Then pack it into a rtp-package with a high enough mtu to have no artefacts and capsulate the rtp-package into a udp-package and stream in to a ip+port.

- Receiver:

  ```
  gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=false
  ```

My understanding of this command is: Receive a udp-package at port 5000. Application says it is a rtp-package inside. I don't know what rtpjitterbuffer does, but it reduces the latency of the video a bit.
rtph264depay says that inside the rtp is a h264-encoded stream. To get the raw data, which fpsdisplaysink understands we need to decode the h264 signal by the use of avdec_h264.

My next step was to change the receiver-sink to a local tcp-sink and output that signal with the following html5-tag:

```
<video width=320 height=240 autoplay>
    <source src="http://localhost:#port#">
</video>
```

If I view the website I can't see the stream, but I can view the videodata, which arrived as plain text, when I analyse the data.

Am I missing a videocontainer like MP4 for my video?
Am I wrong with decoding?
What am I doing wrong?
How can I improve my solution?
How would you solve that problem?

Best regards

Comment: Streaming *live* video to a web browser is not straightforward these days, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788860/current-best-practice-to-stream-live-video-in-web-browser